# install OpenCL for Nvidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, opencl

I installed OpenCL for Nvidia GPU (GTX 285) but OpenCL doesnt work.

`clinfo` (and other apps) shows this error:

```
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
...
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong 
opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
```

The packages that I have installed are:

```
niko@desk:~/binaries/bin$ apt list --installed|grep icd
beignet-opencl-icd/xenial,now 1.1.1-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-340/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
ocl-icd-libopencl1/xenial,now 2.2.8-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

niko@desk:~/binaries/bin$ apt list --installed|grep nvidia
nvidia-340/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-340-uvm/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
nvidia-opencl-dev/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-opencl-icd-340/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-prime/xenial,now 0.8.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/xenial,now 361.42-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

niko@desk:~/binaries/bin$ apt list --installed|grep -i opencl
beignet-opencl-icd/xenial,now 1.1.1-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-dev/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-opencl-icd-340/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates/xenial-updates,now 340.104-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
ocl-icd-libopencl1/xenial,now 2.2.8-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
opencl-headers/xenial,xenial,now 2.0~svn32091-2 all [installed]
unity-scope-openclipart/xenial,xenial,now 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

Full `clinfo` output follows:

```
root@desk:/home/niko/binaries/bin# clinfo
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 6.5.51
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.1.1
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 2
  Device Name                                     GeForce GTX 285
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.0 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  340.104
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.1 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 06:00.0
  Max compute units                               30
  Max clock frequency                             1476MHz
  Compute Capability (NV)                         1.3
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             512x512x64
  Max work group size                             512
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 1       
    short                                                1 / 1       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2146762752 (1.999GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           536690688 (511.8MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       2048 bits (256 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max 2D image size                             4096x16383 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               16384 (16KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        16384
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 Yes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  1
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts  cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 

  Device Name                                     GeForce 8400 GS
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.0 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  340.104
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.0 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 07:00.0
  Max compute units                               2
  Max clock frequency                             918MHz
  Compute Capability (NV)                         1.1
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             512x512x64
  Max work group size                             512
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 1       
    short                                                1 / 1       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               0 / 0        (n/a)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (n/a)
  Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              268238848 (255.8MiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           134217728 (128MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       2048 bits (256 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max 2D image size                             4096x16383 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               16384 (16KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        8192
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 No
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  1
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts  cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics 

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  NVIDIA CUDA
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [NV]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [NV]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              <error: no devices in non-default plaforms>
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.8
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 1.2
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library declares to support OpenCL 1.2,
        but it seems to support up to OpenCL 2.1 too.
root@desk:/home/niko/binaries/bin#
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

My check list for openCL on Ubuntu:

1. The user running the tools and applications needs acces to the video devices. For Ubuntu this requires putting him into group "video".
2. Activate the "Onboard-Video" in your BIOS if you want to access the GPU on the Intel CPU.
3. There's heuristics to find the ICD via the XServer. Therefore unsetting the DISPLAY variable by using commands like "DISPLAY= clinfo" can help depending on your terminal-access (SSH or direct or within X)
4. Use the proprietary NVidia driver. Nouveau doesn't support openCL by 2020/1